# Trigger SBT assembly from other subproject

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a root project containing 3 subprojects plus sbt config files and nothing else. 2 main subprojects are called `server` and `backend`, the other is called `common` and is dependency of both main projects. `server` is PlayFramework project. `backed` project is configured to generate assembly jar into resources directory of `server`.

The jar is generated correctly and server is able to see it, but I don't know how to run `assembly` task from `backend` when `server` is compiled(i.e. I want the server to depend on assembly of backend.jar)

```
/* [...] */

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "0.1",
  organization := "org.example",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
)

lazy val server = (project in file("server")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).settings(commonSettings: _*).settings(
  name := """example""",
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    /* [...] */
  ),
  /* [...] */
  unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += { baseDirectory.value / "resources" }
).dependsOn(common)


lazy val backend = (project in file("backend")).settings(commonSettings: _*).settings(
  assemblyJarName in assembly := "backend.jar",
  assemblyOutputPath in assembly := server.base / "resources/backend.jar",
  libraryDependencies := Seq(

  )
).dependsOn(common)

lazy val common = (project in file("common")).settings(commonSettings: _*)

onLoad in Global := (Command.process("project server", _: State)) compose (onLoad in Global).value
```

Comment: compile in server <<= (compile in server) dependsOn (assembly in backend)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to comment by @pfn I got it working. One thing I needed to do was to insert this line in server subproject settings and change `server` to `Compile`, so it is now:

```
(compile in Compile) <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn (assembly in backend)
```